# Why is it immigrate and emigrate, but import and export (not emport)?

Tags: antonyms, prefixes

Is there a concrete linguistic reason why im- and ex- are used together in the case of goods but im- and em- in the case of people? Clearly, exigrate and emport sound odd, but are they a result of the evolution of language or do the prefixes have different underlying meanings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know English doesn't normally care much about spelling, but look at the spelling anyway. In *immigrate* there are two *m*'s while *emigrate* has only one. Why? Because the first *m* of immigrate comes from the prefix *in-* (the *n* becomes *m* before *m*'s, *p*'s and *b*'s, and sometimes *f*'s and *v*'s), while the second *m* comes from the stem *migrate*.

*Emigrate* meanwhile is formed with the prefix *e-*, a variant of *ex-* that is used in certain contexts, usually where the *x* would be clumsy (in Latin). The proper form of the word if it used *ex-* instead of *e-* would be *exmigrate*, not *exigrate* (likewise, *export* would be *eport* not *emport* if the inverse were true of it).